# How to retrieve associated ManyToOne entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In controller I try to retrieve all order products:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Ordr')->find(1)->getOrdrProducts();
var_dump($products);
```

... but `$products` contain no products.

I try to imitate [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table).

Entity\Ordr.php :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ordr")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ordr
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ordr_products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="idOrdr", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idordr;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrdrProduct", mappedBy="ordr")
     */
    protected $ordr_products;


    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOrdrProducts()
    {
        return $this->ordr_products;
    }

    public function getIdordr()
    {
        return $this->idordr;
    }

    public function addOrdrProducts(\AppBundle\Entity\OrdrProduct $ordrProducts)
    {
        $this->ordr_products[] = $ordrProducts;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrdrProducts(\AppBundle\Entity\OrdrProduct $ordrProducts)
    {
        $this->ordr_products->removeElement($ordrProducts);
    }

}
```

Entity\OrdrProduct.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ordr_products", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idOrdr_idx", columns={"idOrdr"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrdrProduct
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="idOrdrProduct", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idordrproduct;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Ordr", inversedBy="ordr_products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idOrdr", referencedColumnName="idOrdr")
     */
    private $ordr;

    public function getIdordrproduct()
    {
        return $this->idordrproduct;
    }

    public function setOrdr(\AppBundle\Entity\Ordr $ordr = null)
    {
        $this->ordr = $ordr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrdr()
    {
        return $this->ordr;
    }

}
```

My post is mostly code, I apologize for that. I dont know what to add more about the issue.

I can add something more about something else.

Comment: Can you post your Ordr repository class ?

Comment: Validate your mapping first because it looks wrong. Also use word order not ordr. Also why you call your order field order-products? Simply call it products. There are number of books how to write clean code you should read. Have you tried to validate the mapping first via the console tool?

Comment: @mike doctrine:schema:validate says it's OK. (it's just a training code, I purposely named 'ordr' because 'order' throw sql syntax error somehow.)

Comment: @mike "why you call your order field order-products? Simply call it products" I know I can. But it might be handy to get associated things having order object already.

Comment: Always use the $id as primary key. It's easier to do the mapping since this is a default value Doctrine assumes when joining related entities. Summing it up, it's either something wrong with the mapping configuration or there's no data in the related table for given order object in joined tables.

Comment: @mike so You confirm that other than mapping issues or no data it should work. Thats what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

Try this to get one order by id  (with all order products related to it)

```
#AppBundle\Repository\OrderRepository.php 

public function findOrderById($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
                ->join('o.ordr_products', 'r')
                ->addSelect('r')
                ->where('o.id = :id')
                ->setParameter(':id', $id)
        ;
        return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getOneOrNullResult();
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Methods starting with `get` should return an object or throw an exception of one was not found. Methods starting with `find` can return null though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not know that fact.
Question 1: Please do you have a link to share explaining this rule ? 
Question 2: Should I edit my post by renaming my method findOrderById or should I edit the return by using getSingleResult() ?

Comment: It's a known good practice for any object repository in any language. It's up to you if you want to follow this rule and if yes, the method should be renamed or as you suggested the query method used. One you mentioned throws NoResultException if no object was found.

Comment: Thank you very much you teached me a good practice. I Edited My answer.